# Python: How to get single output for nested tuple search?

Tags: python, nested, tuples

v is a variable, e is an expression based tuple with possible nesting

An example of input would be:

`print(isInside('x', (('m', '*', 'x'), '+', 'b')))`

Which should return `True`

But with my code I am getting the output of `(True, False)` because of the nesting

```
def isInside(v, e):

   if len(e) == 0:
        return False
    elif e[0] == v:
        return True
    elif type(e[0]) == tuple:
        return isInside(v, e[0]), isInside(v, e[1:])
    else:
        return isInside(v, e[1:])
```

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want a tuple, why do you *return* a tuple?
I think what you want is the logical **OR** of the two:

```
def isInside(v, e):

    if len(e) == 0:
        return False
    elif e[0] == v:
        return True
    elif type(e[0]) == tuple:
        return isInside(v, e[0]) or  \
               isInside(v, e[1:])
    else:
        return isInside(v, e[1:])

print(isInside('x', (('m', '*', 'x'), '+', 'b')))
```

This returns a simple **True**.

Answer (score 1):

Not really; the problem is this part:

```
isInside(v, e[0]), isInside(v, e[1:])
```

Try replacing it with:

```
isInside(v, e[0]) or isInside(v, e[1:])
```